# onItemAtEndLoaded() method is called only once and doesn't retry again in Paging Library

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, paging

Recently I started working in Kotlin. I am playing around the Paging Library using BoundaryCallback mechanism. It is working nice when there is no failure in API call but in case of failure there is no way to retry the server call. `onItemAtEndLoaded()` never call again.

I've tried all hands including solutions given on different portals. Here below is the PageConfig settings that I am currently using.

```
val pagedConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(DATABASE_PAGE_SIZE)
            .setPrefetchDistance(0)
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .build()
```

I have also tried with ' `setEnablePlacehoder` ' true and false both but no luck. Please help me out if anybody has good experience with paging library.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I use this library.

I found that the best way to refresh content was calling invalidate() on the data source but this only appeals to pull to refresh scenarios when we might want all data to be reloaded.

For implementing retries on failure, it's possible to handle this manually by creating and implementing an interface e.g check out this blog post for an example.

***See Retryable Interface*** : https://medium.com/@SaurabhSandav/using-android-paging-library-with-retrofit-fa032cac15f8